# Optimal Stopping Time Given Range

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

You are presented with a symmetric random walk $X_n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. But with a twist: At any given time $t$, a prophet tells me the range of the random walk $R_{t}$ in the next $T$ steps, where the range is the number of distinct values visited by the walk from $t$ to $t+T$.

At any given point in the walk $\tau$, I can take $X_{\tau}$. My goal is to maximize $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ for any $t$ I choose to take. What is the optimal rule for stopping at any point?

**Thoughts:**

My hunch is to take $X_{\tau}$ whenever it is above the given range, but I can't prove that it's optimal.

Any ideas on how to expand upon this idea or simplify it would be appreciated.

**Relevant References:**

1. [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/ipco17/ipco-talk3.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eanupamg/ipco17/ipco-talk3.pdf)
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophet_inequality
3. [https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~fiat/trading.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Efiat/trading.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by "above the given range"? The "range" was defined to be "the number of distinct values visited by the walk from $t$ to $t+T$". What does it mean for $X_\tau$ to be above the number of distinct values?